# Android Studio would not show map in app

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

Hi I have an app that displays a map. All is good but I want to debug it using the emulator but on the emulator I get this error.

"Google play services not installed on your device!"

OK I dig around and I found it had to do something with the SDK so I made sure all the necessary services under "Extras" are installed and updated. But still no change I keep getting this error and no map is displayed on the emulator. Ok then I dig some more and people say I have to fix my gradel files (I am using facebook SDK too) so this is what I did:

gradle for the app:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/chart.jar')
compile project(':facebook')
/*Adding app Compat to compatibilize Lollipop widgets*/
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
/*Card view (the cute one on lollipop)*/
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
/*recycler view, la posta de la optimizacion*/
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

And the is the gradle file for the facebook SDK:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
}
```

And this is the error messages I get in the logcat:

```
01-29 17:56:15.860    2375-2375/com.myapp.user W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
01-29 17:56:15.880    2375-2375/com.myapp.user W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
01-29 17:56:15.880    2375-2375/com.myapp.user W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
01-29 17:56:15.890    2375-2375/com.myapp.user W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
01-29 17:56:15.940    2375-2410/com.myapp.user W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-29 17:56:15.940    2375-2410/com.myapp.user W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f4811e9a840, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new virtual device from Android Studio, and when the wizard asks you to select a system image, make sure you select an image that says Google APIs(Google Inc) on the target column.

Then when you launch your application make sure you select the emulator image you just created.

Google Play Services and Google maps are only available on Google approved devices and by default are not available on normal emulator images.

Comment: Oh my god ... such a simple mistake ... :D THANK YOU!!